# how to set color in table rows randomly with on click button?

Tags: javascript

this is my code: [link](https://goo.gl/WorXyI)  I have table with 9 row. on click button, one must change color randomly. if I click button once more, it must continue change color randomly

I don't want random color.
I want next thing:

first click: random row must be colorized red

second click:  random row must be colorized red

and so on...

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qsLeejo4/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#btn').on( "click", function() {

var colors = [ 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue' ];

var random  = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
var color   = Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length - 1) + 1);

$($('.col')[random]).css('background-color',colors[color]);

} );
```

You have to give your columns a class too.

Full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/qsLeejo4/5/

Comment: I'm not sure but this will not color 1st `td` . `+1` in random will cause issue. You can use `%` instead.

Comment: You can try something like this: [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/qsLeejo4/7/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I think in general its ok, I just forgot bracket around length -1 => (colors.length - 1).

Comment: w3c use this methode too, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_random2

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is just iterate through `td`s and change their css rules. To generate a random color you can use this snippet:

```
'#' + (~~(Math.random() * (1<<24))).toString(16)
```

Comment: wait, it works but I don't want colorize every row only one click. flow is next

Comment: first click: colorize arndomly only one row,
second click: colorize randomly only one row ...

Comment: and every row must have one color only

Comment: I don't want random color. I want only one color

Answer (score 2):

here is the code it changes first table cell color randomly.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  // math random function

  //rand id
  var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    
  $("#" + id).css("background-color", getRandomColor);
});


function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1" style="width:15%">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">1</td>
    <td id="2">2</td>
    <td id="3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="4">4</td>
    <td id="5">5</td>
    <td id="6">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="7">7</td>
    <td id="8">8</td>
    <td id="9">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: no, no. here color is random but I don't want random color. I want only one color and row's must colorized randomly

Comment: you mean one cell colored randomly??